# How do I email folders containing multiple documents?

Tags: email, compression

I have a folder with 6 documents in it.

If I try to email the folder, my emailer will not accept it.

How do I work around this?

Comment: Is compressing the 6 documents into a .rar archive and sending an option available ?

Comment: Steve B, Please try searching Google before posting questions like this.  Also, @SujithSizon - is this a thing somewhere, somehow? Zip compression is pretty much universally-standard as far as I know.  Unless you intend to send to a group of people who know how to uncompress .rar, I would always suggest zipping something. You didn't even say .7z. You went straight with the .rar response. I think I just lost the ability to even.

Comment: @rubynorails lol sorry , that comment came out like a reflex , because i was just now sending a friend a folder with scanned question papers . :P

Comment: Though this does show a stunning lack of research, I'd say to the close-voters; leave it open - then it becomes research for someone else in future.

Answer (score 4):

You can compress the files into an archive and email that.

1. Select all of the files you want to send
2. Right-click on them and go to **Send to**
3. Click on **Compressed (zipped) folder**

See [Compress and uncompress files - Windows Help](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-ca/windows/compress-uncompress-files-zip-files#1TC=windows-7) for more information.

[image: Send to menu]